# How to upload a file in encrypted form

Tags: c#, encryption, amazon-s3

I am developing an application that will upload files to Amazon.  Amazon provides
a method `WithServerSideEncryptionMethod(ServerSideEncryptionMethod.AES256)` to encrypt files but it is not working. It is saving text as a plain text.

```
public static void UploadFile()
{
    new Program();
    var key = "a";
    //key = ReplaceDblSlashToSingleFwdSlash(key);
    //path = ReplaceFwdSlashToBackSlash(path);
    var request = new PutObjectRequest();
    request.WithBucketName("demo")
           .WithContentBody("i am achal kumar")
           .WithKey(key)
           .WithServerSideEncryptionMethod(ServerSideEncryptionMethod.AES256);
    //request.PutObjectProgressEvent += displayFileProgress;
    S3Response response = s3Client.PutObject(request);
    response.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: How are you verifying the file is not saved encrypted?

Comment: What did Amazon support say when you contacted them?

Comment: How do yoou check that file is stored in plaintext?

Comment: I have go server and login then i see that file is same as i uploaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the following code to check if the is encrypted or not .. because aws s3 they already decrypt the object when they return it to you.

so try the following code to check if the object is encrypted on amazon s3

```
GetObjectMetadataRequest meta = new GetObjectMetadataRequest();

GetObjectMetadataResponse response = s3Client.GetObjectMetadata(meta);
if(response.ServerSideEncryptionMethod = ServerSideEncryptionMethod.AES256)
{
   // your code goes here
}
```

i hope this could help

Answer (score 3):

Your data is likely encrypted and just being automatically decrypted with your get that you are testing with.

http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2011/10/new-amazon-s3-server-side-encryption.html

> Decryption of the encrypted data requires no effort on your part. When
>   you GET an encrypted object, we fetch and decrypt the key, and then
>   use it to decrypt your data. We also include an extra header in the
>   response to the GET to let you know that the data was stored in
>   encrypted form in Amazon S3.